# Why is $P(x)$ allowed to have other variables than $x$ free?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Using the common definition of a propositional function $P(x)$ as "a WFF which would be either true or false were it not for a variable $x$, with other variables also allowed to be free".

For example, if we have a propositional function $P(x)$ with $x$ and $y$ free, then if we only specify $x$, $P(x)$ can still take either "true" or "false" value depending on $y$.

What is the reason for this notation and definition?

Why not define $P(x)$ as "a WFF which would be either true or false were it not for a variable $x$, with no other variables allowed to be free". It would seem much more intuitive if the truth value of $P(x)$ depended on $x$, the truth value of $P(x,y)$ on both $x$ and $y$, etc.

What are the advantages of the former definition over the latter?

Comment: What is the source of the definition ? Compare with [Propositional function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_function).

Answer (score 1):

From :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA74) (1967, also Dover ed), page 74:

> Consider the proposition (expressed by the sentence) "Socrates is a 
>   man". The part of this proposition (expressed by) "— is a man" or "$x$ is 
>   a man" is a predicate; "Socrates" is a subject. Read "$x$ is a man", using 
>   the mathematical notation of a variable, the predicate is seen to be a 
>   *propositional function*, i.e. for each value of the (independent) variable "$x$", it becomes (or takes as value) a proposition, true for example when $x$ is Socrates, false in Greek mythology when $x$ is Chiron, and in the Kleene 
>   household when $x$ is Fleck.

Of course, a *propositional function* may have more than one variable free, like a mathematical function of more than one variable, but it will have a definite truth-value only if a value (or reference) is assigned to all its free variables.

"$x$ is father of $y$" is a propositional function of $x$ and $y$, while "$x$ is father of John" is a propositional function of $x$ alone.

Only "Tom is father of John" is a proposition, i.e. has a truth-value, because it has no more "unsaturated" slots.